Flet build stuck at compiling python sources
I'm trying to build a simple file editor application in flet via python and when I try flet build linux I'm getting the error below.
[02:59:20] Created Flutter bootstrap project from                               
           gh:flet-dev/flet-build-template with ref 0.23.2 ✅                   
           Customized app icons and splash images ✅                            
[03:03:30] Generated app icons ✅                                                                                                      
[03:11:05] Running package command                                                                                                     
           Creating asset directory: /tmp/flet_flutter_build_87YENiTqA8/app                                                            
           Copying Python app from /home/jeff/#pythonProjects/FileEditor to /tmp/serious_python_tempTEMCRM                             
           Installing dependencies  with pip command to /tmp/serious_python_tempTEMCRM/__pypackages__                                  
           Downloading Python distributive from                                                                                        
           https://github.com/indygreg/python-build-standalone/releases/download/20231002/cpython-3.11.6+20231002-x86_64-unknown-linux-
           gnu-install_only.tar.gz to /tmp/cpython-3.11.6+20231002-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-install_only.tar.gz                        
           Extracting Python distributive from /tmp/cpython-3.11.6+20231002-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-install_only.tar.gz to            
           /tmp/hostpython3.11_KXRUUW                                                                                                  
           Compiling Python sources at /tmp/serious_python_tempTEMCRM                                                                  
                                                                                                                                       
           Error building Flet app - see the log of failed command above.          

I tried looking for flet build log file but apparently I can't find it, I don't have any python package requirements in my app.

Did you check the according bug trackers? Point is, you're not programming up to that point at all but just building and installing some software. For a proper question here, you'd need to extract a [mcve] first, but you don't want that. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

try running flet build linux -vv to see what is happening in the logs.
-vv or —-verbose prints you in the terminal a more detailed information about the build. So if you try it, you can upload a more detailed version of your error!
Hope this helps you!

I don't know if this answer will help you or not, but you can try to flet build linux in Google IDX code editor. Just follow below steps.

Sign in to IDX
Make a flutter project.
configure dev.nix file by adding pkgs.python310Full pkgs.python310Packages.pip (for python and pip version 3.10.14)
re-build the environment.
delete all the flutter project related flies and boom!! you got a VM which
support flet build linux.

